# How to stop ModelSim at a condition based on signals?

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, questasim, tcl

From the window, I'd like to give a condition in the console when to stop the simulation.

I've tried:

```
when {/tb/DUT/sequence==256806} {stop}
run -all
```

but it doesn't stop.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Verilog or VHDL test bench?

Comment: The testbench is written in simple systemverilog. I currently have an initial block with `$stop;` as an alternative.

Comment: Calling `$stop` from the initial block is the best way to do it.

Comment: It requires me to recompile the code and rerun the simulation when I want to change the value... when the compilation took hours, I don't really want to rerun it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using (system)verilog for your test bench, you can simply call `$stop` from a procedural block when the desired condition is reached.

If you want to be able to modify the condition from the command line, then you could either use a parameter or signal in the testbench which you force to the desired condition, or initialise a signal from a file which you modify in the command line (e.g. with `$readmemb` or `$readmemh`).

Something like:

```
integer condition;
initial begin
    condition = $readmemh("condition.txt");
    wait(DUT.sequence==condition);
    $stop;
end
```

You should be able to modify the memory file without recompiling.

Or using the force command:

```
integer condition;
initial begin
    wait(DUT.sequence==condition);
    $stop;
end
```

With command `force -freeze /tb/condition 256806` before `run -all`.